# Anyone use SvnMapper?

Tags: svn

First I download SvnMapper([svnmapper.tigris.org](http://svnmapper.tigris.org)) and install it! 
Then I start SvnMapper, the GUI need to input a URL of subversion, I failed in this step.
I have a local repository (means I use `file://` protocol to access the repository myself alone), So I input one of my project svn URL to SvnMapper: `file:///E:/myrepos/mathutil/trunk`, and click OK.
SvnMapper complains: Unable to open URL.

So I guess, SvnMapper may not support file:// protocol. Then I find a project hosted in Google code (http:// protocol), and input the project repository URL to SvnMapper, SvnMapper still complain: Unable to open URL.

What's wrong? I really need a tool like SvnMapper to show good graph representing mergeinfo.

Comment: Same problem a year on.  Can't load http repository.  Maybe it doesn't like password protected repositories.

Answer (score 35):

After the URL was input, I was getting a message box about a thrown 'Softec.AprSharp.Apr' exception on my 64-bit Win7 machine.

I tracked the problem to SvnMapper.exe not having its 32-bit flag set.

To fix it, use **Corflags** which is part of Windows SDK installation accompanying Visual Studio 2010.

Sample command line:

```
corflags "C:\Program Files (x86)\SvnMapper\SvnMapper.exe" /32bit+
```

Obviously, you need the access privilege to modify the EXE file.

Comment: This is great. Worked a treat. Don't forget to right-click and 'Run as Administrator' when starting the Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: If you don't want to download the whole sdk for this, you can get corflags from here: http://www.everything-virtual.com/?p=279. After downloading scan it with something like http://virusscan.jotti.org just be safe!

Comment: I got the error: `corflags : error CF001 : Could not open file for writing` [Turns out I still had SVNMapper running (*blush*); That'll teach me for having too many windows open!]

Comment: Does not work for me. The initial exception disappears, but then I get "Unable to open Url: svn://xxx/yyy Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is rather late for an answer, but there might be something wrong with your original file:// url -- do you need three forward slashes in file:///E:/... ?