# Visualising Subversion branching/merging history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Whenever anyone talks about branching and merging in Subversion, a standard diagram tends to get used:

[image]

Are there any Windows-based tools that will re-create a diagram similar to this that I can use to show the branches in my repository, and their merge/reintegration-merge histories?

I had hoped to use the [TortoiseSVN revision graph](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html) feature to do this, but even with log caching turned on this is very slow and it doesn't seem to show merges anyway, so is only half fit-for-purpose.

Comment: May be to follow the trends and migrate to mercurial or git?

Comment: @zerkms: One of our newer projects (that I hope to be working on later this year) uses git. For now however, I'm stuck with svn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graphical representation of SVN branch/merge activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308/graphical-representation-of-svn-branch-merge-activity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [SVN Mapper](http://svnmapper.tigris.org/).

Features

- Move branches around You can move branches vertically by drgging them with your mouse. Move the entire sub-branch by left-clicking or a single branch by left-clicking + SHIFT
- Name your branches Give your branch a name, and move the name to the right spot.
- View commits Select a branch to view a list the commits of that branch.
- Inspect commits Double click a commit to inspect the list of changes in a commit.
- Inspect changes with Tortoise Double click a change to inspect the difference with Tortoise Diff (if you have it installed).
- Locate parent branches Select a branch to view the list of parent branches (the branches that this branch originates from)
- Hide Branches Hide branches that are not interesting.
- Add merge arrows Annotate your branches with arrows that show merge-sites.
- Scroll Navigation Scroll navigate by clicking the eft mouse button on any empty space.
- Print your branchers Make nice printouts to show your boss.

[image]

Comment: I've found this to be much more useful than TortoiseSVN's revision graph as it's more customisable and better reflects the sort of revision graph you expect to see

Comment: If you are running 64-bit Windows and you get an error after entering the URL then see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147072/anyone-use-svnmapper-please-help-me

Answer (score 1):

Tortoise svn might do what you are looking for.

http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TortoiseSVN try using its revision graphs feature. Please see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308/graphical-representation-of-svn-branch-merge-activity) as well.

Comment: At this time, TortoiseSVN does not render merges